# How do I pass the current record ID as a hidden field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hidden-field

I have a page for viewing each individual customer, which then has a form at the bottom of it to enter a new license, i want that form to automatically fill the hidden field with the id of the current pages customer. Here is the code for my hidden field:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, :value => '1' %>
```

I've currently set the value to 1, which works, but i need it to automatically use the ID instead. this is what's in my controller for this view:

```
def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @license = License.find_by_customer_id(@customer.id)
    @software = Software.all
    @licenses = License.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @customer }
end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try
`<%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, :value => @customer.id %>`

Comment: perfect I knew it was going to be something simple! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Though hidden fields are a good way to pass values across queries, they are not secure especially when you are modifying database records using the values you receive from your clients.

Think of a scenario, where your client is a techie and modifies the value of the hidden field using something like Firebug or a similar tool. And everybody knows that database table IDs are incremental. You'll end up creating licenses for wrong customers.

In my opinion, a good way is to fetch the customer related to your currently logged in user (which you are probably having in session) and then create license for that customer. Or you can store the customer ID in session and then create licenses accordingly.

Please read [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#privilege-escalation).

Comment: Exactly. Never rely on any value coming back from the user the same as it was when you set it. It's trivially simple to change the value of a hidden field, so always consider "What's the worst that can happen if the user changes this?". In your case it sounds like they could access/alter another customer's data, which is pretty bad.

Comment: it's not the customer that'll be logged in, it'll be an administrator, using it to look over the amount of licenses each customer currently has.